# Can I confirm knife action with mouse, or other key than Enter?

Tags: customization, shortcut, knife-tool

Can I confirm knife actions with the mouse, or some other key than <kbd>Enter</kbd>? Going all the way to <kbd>Enter</kbd> breaks the flow in a way that's inconsistent with blender's philosophy.

Comment: [Questions regarding hotkeys](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/290) are regarded as off topic as they are available via User Preferences. See under Input > 3D View > Knife Tool Modal Map.

Comment: @Aldrik it's not entirely about hotkeys per se and OP did not explicitly ask for hotkeys, just if the default could be changed, it's ok *IMO*.

Comment: Oh! Thank you all very much for such a rapid answer. I didn't know hotkeys for tool arguments were listed in the key map and could be customized as well. Sorry for posting such an obvious question. I hope it will be useful for other blender beginners though, I'm not so sure i would have found it without your help. I'll try to search harder next time. Also thank you for the middle mouse button tip - most appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

This is mapped by default to <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> but you can change it if you want to.

---

To change it, you go to *User Preferences* > *Input*.

1. In the search field, type *Knife* and it will bring up the relevant panels
2. Toggle *Knife Topology Tool*
3. Toggle, *Knife Tool Modal Map*
4. Change any of the *Confirm* options to whatever input you want by clicking in the input field to the right and then pressing the key you want to use ***OR***
5. * You can add another one with *Add new* at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go into your *User Preferences* menu, go to the input screen and you will see a drop down menu arrow called knife model tool map, open it up. Go to the arrow which says 'Any number pad enter', this will be on the right side and then click your middle mouse button. The confirm of ending your knife cut will now be assigned to your middle mouse button.